# managing hard-coded file paths/names in code

Tags: c++

I'm looking for the best way to handle hard-coded file paths/names in my code. In future they would be user inputs, but for now they are just hard-coded in code. I have following possible options:

- declare them as private class members and initialize them by constructor
- declare & initialize them inside a namespace and access them through namespace
- declare them as public class members and initialize them by access to public members
- any other possible practice?

I know the best option depends on details of code, but I'm looking for some ideas to pick one.

Comment: This might be a case for a (anti-pattern)  singleton. Create an object which is holding global configuration parameters.

Comment: I don't know much about C++ but could you use a configuration file for them?

Comment: @DieterLücking I just want to make sure I understand: so the idea is to create a class which contains members to store configuration parameters and then instantiate an object of that class. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Always** put a wrapper function around such data. How the function gets the data can be easily modified without upsetting the users of the function.

If the file names are going to be same for all instances of the object, make the function a static member function.

If the file names can be different from one instance of the object to the next, make the function a regular member function.

Comment: I was reading a few times but I'm not yet clear how to implement the wrapper function.

Comment: @user4838962, post some code that you have tried. It will be easier to answer with code when I can see some code :)

Comment: I personally take things a step further.  I would write a placeholder class with access functions for those hardcoded names/paths.   Make sure the interface passes a reference to this placeholder class down into your algorithm.   You can invoke the methods to get the hardcoded strings and such.    Later when the user interface is done, it can construct the real class and populate the strings with the user inputs.   Some people like to make this placeholder a singleton.  I prefer to pass it by reference into the CTORs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a working wrapper class!

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class FilePaths {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_mStrFilePaths;

public:
    FilePaths();
    ~FilePaths();
    std::string getPath( const std::string& strId ) const;
    void addPath( const std::string& strFilePath );

private:    
    FilePaths( const FilePaths& c );
    FilePaths& operator=( const FilePaths& c );

}; // FilePaths


static unsigned uId = 0; // Initialize to 0 - This should be in your class.cpp file!
FilePaths::FilePaths() {
    m_mStrFilePaths.clear();
} // FilePaths

FilePaths::~FilePaths() {
    m_mStrFilePaths.clear();
} // ~FilePaths

std::string FilePaths::getPath( const std::string& strId ) const {
    if ( strId.empty() ) {
        // Return Error Or If In Try Catch Block Throw Error    
        return std::string();
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it = m_mStrFilePaths.find( strId );
    if ( it == m_mStrFilePaths.cend() ) {
        // Not Found
        // Return Error Or If In Try Catch Block Throw Error    
        return std::string();
    }
    return it->second;
} // getPath

void FilePaths::addPath( const std::string& strFilePath ) {
    if ( strFilePath.empty() ) {
        // Return Error Or If In Try Catch Block Throw Error    
        return;
    }

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << "Id_" << ++uId;

    m_mStrFilePaths[strStream.str()] = strFilePath;
} // addPath

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    FilePaths paths;

    // I have double slashes in the strings here because of the escape sequence /P
    paths.addPath( std::string( "C:\\PathA" ) );
    paths.addPath( std::string( "C:\\PathB" ) );
    paths.addPath( std::string( "C:\\PathC" ) );

    std::string myPath = paths.getPath( std::string( "Id_2" ) );

    std::cout << myPath << std::endl;

    // Has No Meaning - I put a break point on this line to stop execution from closing the console.
    std::cout << "Pause On This Line" << std::endl;

    return 0;
 } // main
```

Now if you want to be a little more strict with this, you can inherit this class from a base class that is a singleton so you can only ever create one instance of this object, but you would then need a static get method defined in this class that would return this classes pointer upon construction. Then you can use a const global pointer to this anywhere in your project where it is needed.

It would be better to have a error handling class for catching and throwing exceptions! This way if the path being entered in to store or the string id to find is invalid an exception will be thrown. Now you do not have to use a string as an ID, you can use an unsigned int and associate these unsigned int key values in this map with a global enum, but this is a little simpler to work with and is a little more friendlier to read and use.

This should get you started and I hope this helps!

As a note after reading this I updated one of this class's methods from setPath to addPath. I changed this because set sounds more like a single value being set into a single member variable, where add sounds more like putting in an element into a container. It just has a little more clarity to it for a reason of preference, not that the existing code was wrong or didn't work.

Comment: The reason I used an unordered map as opposed to a vector is that you can find your path via a string index which returns the appropriate string! The user will have to know the indexing of the map! Also, later on when you decide to allow user input to add in the file path, you can use the cin or get line call and save that to a string passing it right into this classes addPath() method.

Comment: Example helped me a lot. I wonder if this is possible: inside my original class, I declare a `static` member with the type of your wrapper class, so that file names/paths can be the same for all instances of my original class. Would it be an alternative way to avoid using singleton?

Comment: I feel like it's not possible to declare a `static` member of type class inside another class in C++.

Comment: You can have nested classes. If you only need this in one specific class, then you could make this class either protected or private but would have to have public methods in your existing class to call this class's methods. I do not think there would be a need for a static member. Since this nested class would live as long as its parent class is in scope. You could also just have this as a separate class and just have it as private member variable that could be a unique_ptr<>().

Comment: You can have a static pointer to another class within a class, but the class that you are pointing to must have a static get() method that will return its (this) pointer upon construction.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that could help you is to have all of your FilePaths in a text file where each one is on their own line terminated by a carriage return. Then write a small parser function to read that text file line by line that would read in each lines contents and save it to a string. Then after you have that string you could use the above wrapper class to store its contents by passing in the string you got from the parser. This way if you need to fix or change the FilePaths, you can just edit the text file and will not have to recompile or rebuild your code everytime you change or add a FilePath! This would create an automatic process!